# Leer un valor en concreto de JSON en Java

Tags: java, android, json, api, arraylist

Estoy haciendo una app en Android estudio utilizando una API que devuelve lo siguiente:

```
[
  {
   "domains": ["upes.ac.in"],

   "country": "India",

   "state-province": "Dehradun", 

   "web_pages": ["https://www.upes.ac.in/"], 

   "name": "University of Petroleum and Energy Studies", "alpha_two_code": "IN"
  }
]
```

Lo recorro de la siguiente manera:

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
            listaUniversidades = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                String nombreUni, pais, url;

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    nombreUni = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                    pais = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("country");
                    url = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("web_pages"));
                  
                    texto.setText(url);

                    listaUniversidades.add(new Universidad(nombreUni, pais, url));
                }}
```

La cosa es que el web_pages me devuelve lo siguiente: ["http://.www.upes.ac.in/"]

¿Como podría hacer para que me devuelva la URL bien? Ya que de esa forma no puedo acceder a la web de la universidad.

Gracias!

Comment: Usa `url = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("web_pages").getString(0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de realizar esto, para obtener el valor de la url.

1)Como el valor de la url se encuentra dentro de un array,

```
"web_pages": ["https://www.upes.ac.in/"],
```

Obtén el valor del primer elemento del array (indice 0):

```
url = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("web_pages").getString(0);
```

2)Otra opción es utilizar `replace()` de esta forma:

```
url = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("web_pages").replace("[","").replace("]","");
```

Comment: Gracias! Por la respuesta, me ha funcionado!

Comment: @Sarrus excelente saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una manera más o menos compleja para resolverlo. También modifique la estructura de tu JSON.

1. Cree una clase Dominios.java con la estructura del JSON
2. Se obtienen los valores del String de los elementos del JSON.
3. Una vez obtenidos los valores, accedemos a la lista que contiene las web pages y mostramos la URL.

**Dominios.java**

```
package com.java.models;

import java.util.List;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Dominios {
    private List<String> domains;
    private List<String> webPages;
    private String country;
    private String stateProvidence;
    private String name;
    private String alphaTwoCode;
}
```

**Main.java**

```
package com.java;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.lang.System.err;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import com.curso.java.models.Dominios;

public class Main{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      final String strJson = "{'domains':['upes.ac.in'],'country':'India','state-province':'Dehradun','web_pages':['https://www.upes.ac.in/'],'name':'University of Petroleum and Energy Studies','alpha_two_code':'IN'}";
        Dominios dominios = new Dominios();
        List<String> domains = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> webPages = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject jsonObj = null;
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        try{
            out.println("Entrada: "+strJson);
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            if(jsonObj!=null){
                jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("domains");
                for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    domains.add(""+jsonArray.get(i));
                }

                out.println(domains);

                jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("web_pages");
                for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    webPages.add(""+jsonArray.get(i));
                }
                out.println(webPages);
                dominios.setAlphaTwoCode(jsonObj.getString("alpha_two_code"));
                dominios.setCountry(jsonObj.getString("country"));
                dominios.setName(jsonObj.getString("name"));
                dominios.setStateProvidence(jsonObj.getString("state-province"));
                dominios.setDomains(domains);
                dominios.setWebPages(webPages);

                out.println("Salida: "+dominios);

                out.println("URL: "+dominios.getWebPages().get(0));

            }
        }catch(JSONException jse){
            err.println("JSONException: "+jse.getMessage());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            err.println("Exception al obtener objeto: "+ex.getMessage());
        }

   }

}
```

Es una forma de acceder a los elementos JSON. La salida del programa es la siguiente.

```
Entrada: {'domains':['upes.ac.in'],'country':'India','state-province':'Dehradun','web_pages':['https://www.upes.ac.in/'],'name':'University of Petroleum and Energy Studies','alpha_two_code':'IN'}
[upes.ac.in]
[https://www.upes.ac.in/]
Salida: Dominios(domains=[upes.ac.in], webPages=[https://www.upes.ac.in/], country=India, stateProvidence=Dehradun, name=University of Petroleum and Energy Studies, alphaTwoCode=IN)
URL: https://www.upes.ac.in/
```

Como se puede observar, obtenemos la URL del web pages.

Comment: Gracias! Por la respuesta, tambien me ha servido!